# Different BG on different sides

Tags: html, css

I want to have a different color on the right of an image and on the left. Right now, the CSS looks like this:

```
#header {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 199px;
    background: url('img/header.jpg');
}

#header-bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: #161b1c url('img/header-line.gif');
}
```

While the `#header-bg` is the actual background to the right and to the left (it also contains a line, but that is irrelevant) and it goes to 100% of the width. When I change the color `#161b1c`, I change both left and right side of the header. I would like to differentiate between those two. Is there any other way apart from doing it with the help of an image?

I enclose a mockup of the site:

[image: mockup]

This is the markup:

```
<div id="header-bg">
    <div id="header"></div>
</div>
<div id="site"></div>
```

Comment: Just add some div's to make proper markup and change colors as needed

Comment: can we sse your HTML markup please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the `:after` pseudo element and the `z-index` property :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/87LMn/5/)**

CSS :

```
#header {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 199px;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-1000-239-1.jpg');
    position:relaive;
    z-index:2;
}
#header-bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: #161b1c url('img/header-line.gif');
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#header-bg:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: gold;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for lorempixel! Never knew about it. You get an upvote just for THAT! :-)

Comment: @TimSPQR yes it is great I would like prettyer photos but it is very handy